# Why do these trait implementations conflict and how can I work around it?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a trait for an Encoder trait using bounds, however because something could share both a serde::Serialize and a prost::Message trait these conflict and this code doesn't compile.

```
pub trait KafkaMessageEncoder {
    fn encode_bytes(&self) -> anyhow::Result<Vec<u8>>;
}

impl<T: serde::Serialize> KafkaMessageEncoder for T {
    fn encode_bytes(&self) -> anyhow::Result<Vec<u8>> {
        serde_json::to_vec(&self).map_err(anyhow::Error::new)
    }
}

impl<T: prost::Message> KafkaMessageEncoder for T {
    fn encode_bytes(&self) -> anyhow::Result<Vec<u8>> {
        Ok(self.encode_to_vec())
    }
}
```

However I'm a bit at a loss as to what's the correct pattern here.  How can I implement multiple bounded traits?  You can't use the `!` operator to exlude things

Comment: You can use a newtype.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that a type could implement both traits and then the call to `KafkaMessageEncoder::encode_bytes()` would be ambiguous.

Currently Rust does not have a mechanism to specify negative bounds, so the easiest way is to use a new-type pattern, as @ChayimFriedman commented above.

There is a compromise between the complexity of the new-type solution and the ergonomics of its usage. I like to write something like this (untested):

```
struct SerdeWrapper<T>(T);

trait SerdeWrap {
    fn as_serde(&self) -> SerdeWrapper<&Self> {
        SerdeWrapper(self)
    }
}
impl<T: serde::Serialize> SerdeWrap for T {}

struct ProstWrapper<T>(T);

trait ProstWrap {
    fn as_prost(&self) -> ProstWrapper<&Self> {
        ProstWrapper(self)
    }
}
impl<T: prost::Message> ProstWrap for T {}



impl<T: serde::Serialize> KafkaMessageEncoder for SerdeWrapper<&T> {
    // ....
}

impl<T: prost::Message> KafkaMessageEncoder for ProstWrapper<&T> {
    // ....
}

pub fn test1<T: serde::Serialize(t: &T) {
    t.as_serde().encode_bytes();
}

pub fn test2<T: prost::Message(t: &T) {
    t.as_prost().encode_bytes();
}
```

It should be zero-cost, and it solves the possible ambiguity quite nicely, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because there is possibility for type `T` which implements **both** traits `serde::Serialize` and `prost::Message` so it would have 2 implementations of KafkaMessageEncoder so it would not know how to choose between them.

You have an option to declare a new type for that.

```rust
struct SerdeEncodered<T: serde::Serialize>(T);

struct ProstEncodered<T: prost::Message>(T);

// This implementations cannot conflict
// because compiler know types and know that they are different.

impl<T: serde::Serialize> KafkaMessageEncoder for SerdeEncodered<T> {
    fn encode_bytes(&self) -> anyhow::Result<Vec<u8>> {
        serde_json::to_vec(&self.0).map_err(anyhow::Error::new)
    }
}

impl<T: prost::Message> KafkaMessageEncoder for ProstEncodered<T> {
    fn encode_bytes(&self) -> anyhow::Result<Vec<u8>> {
        Ok(self.0.encode_to_vec())
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that they implement both traits.  I suppose it's too complex for the compiler to add some sort of mutually exclusive implementation, like implements one trait but not another.  In practice this models quite a few real world scenarios.  I ended up taking your approach exactly (pretty much).